# buffer and file size in assembly x86 ia-32

Tags: assembly, system-calls, x86

I'm playing with assembly on Linux x86 (IA-32) and i encountered some problems during the `read` syscall.

```
global _start
section .text
_start:
        mov eax,5 ;open
        mov ebx,filename ;path to file
        mov ecx,0000o ;O_RDONLY
        int 0x80 
        mov ebx,eax ;fd in ebx
        mov eax,3 ;read
        ;buffer?
        ;count?;
        int 0x80
        mov eax,0x1 ;exit
        mov ebx,0x5 ;ret code
        int 0x80

section .data 
        filename: db "path-to-file"
```

I have two problems because:

1. how can i define a buffer in asm?
2. how can i set `count`? I need to know the file size but...how can i get this in asm?

Comment: You can use `sys_fstat` to get the file size, and e.g. `sys_brk` to allocate memory for a buffer. See http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html for a list of syscalls.

Comment: mmm ok thanks! Another doubt: how can i pass the parameter `struct __old_kernel_stat *` to the ecx reg??

Comment: It's a pointer, i.e. an address to a chunk of memory large enough to hold a `struct stat`.

Comment: ok! So in x86 `sizeof(struct stat)` is 88 bytes so i need 88 bytes into the .bss section right? Then to access the file size i need to do a `lea edx,[var-in-bss-section]+32` because the `long st_size` is the 9th element inside the struct and there are 8 elements each one is 4 bytes. Am i right?

Comment: You can declare structs in nasm (see e.g. http://mcs.uwsuper.edu/sb/224/Intro/struct_nasm.html)

Comment: i opened a specific question, thanks :)